# How to get call back of Google location service dialog button click's in flutter?

Tags: flutter, geolocation, flutter-dependencies

I need to fetch current location of device in my Flutter App. I have added plugins are location: ^2.3.5 and geolocator: ^5.0.1 to get current location.
All is working fine but when the GPS of my device is off(disabled) then it shows a dialog that i have shown in Image please check it.I need call back on press ok button so that i can get current location and execute next code lines. I will be thankful to you if you help me.

[image]

Here have some code.

```
getCurrentLocation() async{
try {
   await location.getLocation().then((locationData){
     if(locationData!=null){
     moveHomeWithLatLon(context,false,locationData.latitude.toString(),locationData.longitude.toString());
   }else{
     dialogInternetCheck(context, alert, "Please check location services on device");
   }
  });
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
    error = 'Permission denied';
    dialogInternetCheck(context, alert, "Location services "+error);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should check for the **service status result** after requesting location service. If it is true that means the user has provided the access. I have provided the example below

```
bool serviceStatusResult = await location.requestService();
 print("Service status activated after request: $serviceStatusResult");
  if (serviceStatusResult) {
    await _getCurrentLocation();
  }

Future<bool> _getCurrentLocation() async {
try {
  Location location = Location();
  LocationData userLocation = await location.getLocation();
 } on PlatformException catch (e) {
  Log.info("Location fetch failed : ${e.toString()}");
 }
 return Future.value(true);
}
```

Comment: I tried the same code, but not able to execute print statement for     serviceStatusResult.
Please suggest.

Comment: I checked running the code again in Android and it prints the service status.